# Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $d_n := \sqrt[n]{d}$. Then $d_n$ is a metric that induces the same topology as $d$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to extend [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554203/triangle-inequality-and-the-square-root-of-a-metric-space) result, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $n \in \mathbb N^*$. Let $d_n := \sqrt[n]{d}$. Then $d_n$ is a metric on $E$ and induces the same topology as $d$.

Could you have a check if my attempt is fine?

---

*Proof:* Clearly, $d_n (x,y)=0 \iff d(x, y)=0$. Let's prove that $d_n$ satisfies the triangle inequality. This follows directly from the following lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $a,b,c \ge 0$ such that $a \le b + c$. If $n \in \mathbb N^*$ then $\sqrt[n]{a} \le \sqrt[n]{b} + \sqrt[n]{c}$.
>
> *Proof:* By Binomial theorem, we have
> $$
> (\sqrt[n]{b} + \sqrt[n]{c})^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} b^{(n-k)/n} c^{k/n} = b+c + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} b^{(n-k)/n} c^{k/n}.
> $$
> Then $(\sqrt[n]{b} + \sqrt[n]{c})^{n} \ge a$. The claim then follows.

To see that $d$ and $d_n$ induce the same topology on $E$, we notice that $d_n (x, y) < r \iff d (x, y) < r^n$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Your argument is fine.